# Permanent residency from Sweden while I have permanent residency from Germany due to marriage?

Tags: resident-permit, eu, eu-spouses

Apparently, getting a permanent residency from a second EU country would make the first permanent residency void. But if I have a German permanent residency due to marriage with a German citizen, and now want to apply for permanent residency in Sweden, what would happen to my German PR? Would PR due to marriage expire at all? Can I have both PRs?

Thanks.

Comment: Your status as a "long-term resident" would likely lapse, but you would be able to move back to Germany under the directive linked in the other answer or, if your spouse is in Germany, under the freedom of movement directive.

Comment: Alright. But can I just continue working in Sweden without applying for "Permanent" residency and just obtain residence permit?